# Stochastic process inference from partial observations

Tags: sampling, estimation, statistics, reconstruction, random

Consider a set $U$. My signal is a piece-wise constant "function"
$Sig: t \mapsto s$, i.e. the signal at time $t$ equals to some subset
$s \subset U$. One can see $Sig(t)$ as a stochastic process.

For a given sequence of time points $\{t_i\}$, we have sequence of
partial observations $\{ Ob(t_i) \}$. Each observation $Ob(t_i)$ is
not a noised value of $Sig(t_t)$, but rather a "random" part of the "real"
signal. I mean:

$$ Ob(t_i) \subset Sig(t_i) \,.$$

(For example, $Sig(t_i)$ can be a graph, and $Ob(t_i)$ will result in a random subgraph of $Sig(t_i)$).

Is there a theory that describes such partially observed stochastic
processes?  In particular, is there a method to infer (estimate) the
parameters of the underlying stochastic process $Sig(t)$ using only a
given sequence of observations $\{Ob(t_i)\}$?

If you want to add some addition properties (constraints) to $Sig(t)$ or to $Ob(t)$, you are welcome.

### Update:

For example, a very simple problem from this class is considered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/if-maria-performs-more-observations-per-unit-of-time-than-maximilien-how-can-he

Comment: Maybe you could try to dial it down a specific application, because with this general description is too mathematical to be able to point out a particular model or theory that would work.
but you could look into hidden markov models, a good way to estimate the true states of a hidden markov model based on observations is the Viterbi Algorithm

Comment: I second @bone's suggestion: have a look at hidden Markov models and some of their extensions.

Comment: @bone and Peter K., Thank you! I should certainly think about the Markov chains, but the problem is that we can easily have an infinite number of hidden states...

Comment: That's why I added "and extensions. See, for example, http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips14/AA01.pdf